# specify a .htaccess rewrite rule to open a pdf file

Tags: .htaccess

I want a rewrite rule in my htaccess file that if someone calls

```
www.domain.de/test
```

a specified PDF is opened

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below rule will rewrite to the location of pdf, showing of pdf will depend upon your sethandler rule in apache config.

I am assuming root is the location.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test$ /file.pdf [L]
```